# upsert the data when source table contains duplicate records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source table and a target table in Snowflake, both with columns `order_id`, `sku_id`, `status`, and `updated_date`. I want to perform an `upsert` operation, updating the status in the target table with the corresponding status from the source table where there are duplicates at the order_id and sku_id granularity. Additionally, I only want to fetch records from the last 2 days in the source table.

Here's an example of my updated source and target tables:

**Source Table:**

| order_id | sku_id | status | updated_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o1 | s1 | return & refund | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s2 | return & refund | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s1 | delivered | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s2 | delivered | 2024-01-15 |
| o2 | s3 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o2 | s4 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o3 | s5 | placed | 2024-01-15 |

**Target Table:**

| order_id | sku_id | status | updated_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o1 | s1 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o1 | s2 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o2 | s3 | shipped | 2024-01-13 |
| o2 | s4 | shipped | 2024-01-13 |

**I want to ensure that duplicate records (here delivered and refund & refund status) at the order_id and sku_id level from the last 2 days are updated in the target table** with the corresponding status from the source table and insert if new record at `order_id - sku_id` level.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this in Snowflake SQL, following best practices?

**Expected Updated Target Table:**

| order_id | sku_id | status | updated_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o1 | s1 | return & refund | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s2 | return & refund | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s1 | delivered | 2024-01-15 |
| o1 | s2 | delivered | 2024-01-15 |
| o2 | s3 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o2 | s4 | out for delivery | 2024-01-14 |
| o3 | s5 | placed | 2024-01-15 |

I have tried with this merge (upsert) option snowflake provide but not getting updated records.

```
merge target_table as t using
(select order_id, sku_id, status, updated_date
 from source_table 
 where date(updated_date) >= current_date -2) as s
on s.order_id = t.order_id and s.sku_id = t.sku_id
when matched then update set
t.order_id = s.order_id,
t.sku_id = s.sku_id,
t.status = s.status,
t.updated_date = s.updated_date
when not matched then 
insert (
order_id,
sku_id,
status,
updated_date
)
values(
s.order_id,
s.sku_id,
s.status,
s.updated_date
)
;
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you add `QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by order_id, sku_id order by....) = 1` to your source table select statement.  In your case, I suspect an order by using update_date and some sort of case statement that orders your statuses would be necessary.

Comment: But I need the duplicate records at order_id-sku_id level in my target table

Comment: Then you need to add the other columns to your join condition.  What makes the records unique in your target table?  If you need every transaction from the source, then what is it that is being updated?  If just the updated date, then add status to the join condition.  If nothing is being updated, then just use an insert.  It doesn't sound like they are "duplicates" at all.

Comment: Ideally the uniqueness should be at order_id - sku_id - status and this works fine until order_id status is delivered and then customer return the order then 2 entries are created for that order becoz we need both delivered and return & refund entry which makes it not unique and this case happens only when customer returns the order.
How to handle this edge case?

Comment: In this edge case, do you want to keep both records or just choose the latest record and update the updated_date?  To use MERGE correctly, you need to choose the uniqueness of the data that you are storing.  If you want one record for order_id - sku_id, then that's your uniqueness.  If you want to include all statuses for that order/sku, then include status in the join condition.  And so on.

Comment: I want to keep both records and update the updated_date. This is hampering uniqueness for these orders and i want know if there any way to handle this in my merge statement?

Comment: Then join on everything except updated_date.  When matched, update the updated_date.  When not, insert new record.  Pretty simple.